# Kivy - How to drag and drop items from ScrollView to another layout?

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

I'm attempting to drag some images arranged inside a GridLayout (which is indeed inside a ScrollView) to outer Layout.

The image to be dragged has its `on_touch_down` event defined, when image is clicked parent is changed from `WidgetMenu` to `MainLayout` so it can be dragged between those widgets. The current problem is when I touch the image, DragBehavior is lost.

The full code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview    import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<WidgetMenu>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.9,0.5,0.3
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [20,]
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding:30

    ScrollView:

        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            size_hint_y:None
            row_default_height:root.height*.15
            height:self.minimum_height
            DragImage:
            DragImage:
            DragImage:


<DragImage>:
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 100000000
    drag_distance: 0
    size_hint:None,None
    size:234,34
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb:1,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<MainLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb:1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    WidgetMenu:
        size_hint: 0.35,0.9

''')

class MainLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass
class WidgetMenu(BoxLayout):
    pass
class DragImage(DragBehavior,FloatLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        workspace = self.parent.parent.parent.parent
        grid = self.parent
        menu = self.parent.parent.parent
        if "MainLayout" in str(workspace):
            grid.remove_widget(self)
            workspace.remove_widget(menu)
            self.pos = Window.mouse_pos
            workspace.add_widget(self)
        return True

class ScrollApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()

ScrollApp().run()
```

Please help.

Comment: I suspect your `on_touch_down()` method should not `return True`, but should `return super(DragImage, self).on_touch_down(touch)`

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems with your code are that you are not calling the super method in your `on_touch_down`, and placing the `DragImage` in the top level `MainLayout` changes the `pos` of the `DragImage`, thus changing its `DragRectangle`. That change in `DragRectangle` leaves the `touch.pos` outside of it, so `DragBehavior` thinks the touch is not on the `DragImage`.

I have fixed both those problems by calling the super method and changing the `touch.pos` before passing it to the super method. I also added some code to keep the `DragImage` in the same position relative to the mouse when it is clicked. Also added a call to `self.collide_point()` in order to ignore clicks not on the `DragImage`.

```
class DragImage(DragBehavior,FloatLayout):
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return False
        workspace = self.parent.parent.parent.parent
        grid = self.parent
        menu = self.parent.parent.parent
        if "MainLayout" in str(workspace):
            grid.remove_widget(self)
            workspace.remove_widget(menu)

            # the following code assumes that workspace is the entire Window
            self.x = Window.mouse_pos[0] - (touch.pos[0] - self.x)
            self.y = Window.mouse_pos[1] - (touch.pos[1] - self.y)
            workspace.add_widget(self)
            touch.pos = Window.mouse_pos
        return super(DragImage, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```